# Collaborative Worldbuilding sites or tools?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources, shared-worlds

Are there *existing* *collaborative websites* (or tools) for world building ? Examples of result could be very developed creations like http://www.orionsarm.com, or roleplay universes.

I do not need/want to create a website by myself (this topic is covered by other questions), but have feedback on existing tools, especially regarding the usability, the ways to manage the contributors (motivate and reward people) and the creation (reviews, votes on suggestions, etc.).

Comment: There is already a meta-post about this, but I am currently too lazy to search it. I will look for it next year. There is a GitHub-Organization, but we are currently lacking someone who really drives the project. I am happy to provide organisation-help, but can't provide content at the moment. https://github.com/Worldbuilding-Workshop

Comment: By the way, this is worldbuilding, but only as a meta. Relocate?

Comment: @RileySantos I think this fits the [tag:worldbuilding-resources] tag, so I think it's okay on the main site (just my opinion).

Comment: Seconded with HDE, worldbuilding resources are on topic. Talking about making one would be for meta, but asking if they exist is fine here.

Comment: Uriel, could you tell us if that question above answers your question?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin, The proposed answer suggestions about ho to build your own collaborative platform (versionning, web access tips, etc.) but does not provide existing tools/website. So it does not answer.

Comment: @Uriel, could you edit your question, to be more explicit about what you want and why the other answers are not what you are looking for? (essentially writing the same as in the comment, but in your question it is more clear)

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin : done

Comment: @J_F_B_M using a git repository is an interesting option. I'll keep it in mind, as well as a wiki-based option, should nothing exist;.

Comment: @Uriel wow, that's a ping from the past :D My offer for organisation-help still stands. If I recall right I wrote a **Git for Dummies**, which should be *somewhere* on the repo. If not I can try to find it elsewhere, I have quite some Tutorial-PDFs I produced in my Documents-Folder. Maybe we can ask one of our new gods to reopen the chat.

Comment: @J_F_B_M : I had a look in the git repo already, and I am quite familiar with such tool. No need for specific help for the moment. I expected collaborative tools to be common, but it does not seem to be the case. Thanks for your support :)